# Change Countdown Download button to text display button

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to create a countdown button that will show hidden text after a certain time.
Here is the code about downloading files after 5 seconds.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e48d166edc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Download Button With Timer</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="download-container">
    <a href="#" class="download-btn"> <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt "></i> Download Now</a>
    <div class="countdown"></div>
  
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const downloadBtn = document.querySelector(".download-btn");
  const countdown = document.querySelector(".countdown");
  const pleaseWaitText = document.querySelector(".pleaseWait-text");
  const manualDownloadText = document.querySelector(".manualDownload-text");
  const manualDownloadLink = document.querySelector(".manualDownload-link");
  var timeLeft = 5;

  downloadBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    downloadBtn.style.display = "none";
    countdown.innerHTML = "Your download will start in <span>" + timeLeft + "</span> seconds."  //for quick start of countdown

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function timeCount() {
      timeLeft -= 1;
      countdown.innerHTML = "Your download will start in <span>" + timeLeft + "</span> seconds.";

      if(timeLeft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        pleaseWaitText.style.display = "block";
        let download_href = "Testfile.rar"; //enter the downlodable file link here
        window.location.href = download_href;
        manualDownloadLink.href = download_href;

        setTimeout(() => {
          pleaseWaitText.style.display = "none";
        manualDownloadText.style.display = "block"
        }, 4000);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
  
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to change it to a button, which will show a text after 5 minutes and can be put in WordPress post, but I don't know how to do it.
Please help me.

Comment: You're trying to access elements that don't exist in the markup so you're getting an error.

Comment: Can you tell me more clearly? Sorry I don't know much about code html

Comment: In the code provided you reference elements such as `manualDownloadText` or `pleaseWaitText` etc but these elements do NOT appear in the HTML so you would get errors in your Javascript code  as a result.

Comment: Thank you @Professor Abronsius, but I want to create a countdown button to display text after a few second. For example: "Click to get your code", after click and wait for some seconds user will get their code.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to describe exactly what should happen that might help?

Comment: Please check the code in the comment below. Let me explain: searching for a keyword on Google to find a website link, click on it, scroll down to find the button, after click on it and wait for some seconds this button will show a text. However if you click that link directly on the website you cannot see the button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to put in wordpress, it will display text after click and wait for a few seconds. But I don't know why it doesn't work.

This code is used for the button

```html
<div id="references40" code-ref="ref51" countdown="8" style="text-align: center; font-weight: 600;"> BUTTON CHỈ HIỆN MẬT KHẨU KHI TÌM TỪ KHÓA "SHARE COOKIES NETFLIX" TRÊN GOOGLE </div>
```

This code is put in the body of wordress

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" >

var referrer = document.referrer;
ifm_list_browser = ['google.com', 'google.com.vn'];

function checkFefer(f, e) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        if (f.indexOf(e[i]) > -1) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

let stores = {
    'ref48': 'ký tự đặc biệt',
    'ref49': 'các bạn có thể chèn số 122344',
    'ref50': 'đây là demo vui vẻ',
    'ref51': '343596',
}

var flagref = checkFefer(referrer, ifm_list_browser)
if (flagref) {
    var html = '<p style="text-align:center;"><button style="background: #e81e1e;border-radius: 10px;border:none;color: #ffffff;width: 59%;padding: 10px 0;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;outline: none; cursor: pointer;" id="countDown40" get-code="true" class="coundownmobile" onclick="startcountdown(); this.onclick=null;">Lấy mã bảo mật</button></p>';
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#references40").empty();
        html = $.parseHTML(html);
        $("#references40").append(html);
    });

}

function startcountdown() {
    document.getElementById('countDown40').setAttribute("style", "background: #0b1df5;border-radius: 10px;border:none;color: #ffffff;width: 59%;padding: 10px 0;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;outline: none; cursor: pointer;");
    let cNode = jQuery("#references40");
    let cKey = cNode.attr('code-ref');
    let cCount = cNode.attr('countdown');
    let counter = parseInt(cCount) || 40;
    var countdownCode = setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        document.getElementById('countDown40').innerHTML = 'Mã bảo mật sẽ hiện sau ' + counter + ' giây' + ' bạn  nhé';
        if (counter == 0) {
            document.getElementById('countDown40').innerHTML = `Mã bảo mật của bạn là: ${stores[cKey]}`;
            document.getElementById('countDown40').setAttribute("style", "background: #ea3b7b;border-radius: 10px;border:none;color: #ffffff;width: 59%;padding: 10px 0;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;outline: none; cursor: pointer;");
            clearInterval(countdownCode);
            return false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

</script>
```

Comment: This bears no resemblance whatsoever to the code in the original question

Comment: Yes, but it has the same purpose. I tried many codes to create a button which have countdown timer and can change the text.